# Vue props undefined on component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am struggling with passing props to my child component and reading through many many examples, there are quiet a few in my position. Seems this shouldn't be so complicated, right?
Ideally, when I drop my component on a html page I want to be able to pass a url as an attribute. Example
`<landingpage myUrl="http://localhost"><landingpage>` but when I inspect with the Vue Dev Tools in browser, it is always undefined. I've seen a hack using JQuery to select the element and then get the attribute but I would like to do it in pure Vue. 
In my code below, no variation of "title" is passed to my component.

In my index.html page I have this

```
     <body>
    <p>Hello world, this is some text. Howdy.</p>
    <div id="NewWidget">
      <div id="app" data-title="mario" :data-title="luigi" :title="princess">
        <landingpage title="hello!" :title="spaghetti" v-bind:title="Nervos"></landingpage>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
```

In my App.vue I have

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

And in my landingpage.vue I have this

```
export default {
  name: 'landingpage',
  data () {
    return {
      categories: [],
    }
  },
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String
    }
  },
...
```

My router index.js

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'LandingPage',
      component: LandingPage,
      props: true
    },
...
```

In my LandingPage component, this.title is always null/undefined. 
I am using Vue 2.5.2 / Vue Router 3.0.1 
Only thing I can think of is my VueRouter usage in App.vue is burning the props?

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you have an index.html which doesn't use vue-router and then you have an App.vue that does use vue-router. Also I would only try one method of passing props at a time, in this case title="hello!" is the correct one and the others will throw errors.

Comment: Are you saying in my index.html page i should be referencing <router-view/> instead of <landingpage/>?

Comment: Yes, that's how I've done it before. <router-view /> then selects the correct view based on how you've setup the routing with vue-router

Comment: Ive tried that but then I'm assuming if I wanted to pass attributes with it, I would be writing <landingpage myUrl="google.com"></landingpage>  but that property of "myUrl" never appears anywhere lower down the DOM

Comment: If you use the <router-view /> in your index.html, the only place you should reference landing page is in the router setup in your index.js. [Here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-props/app.js) is a pretty good example of the suggested setup and they pass some props in the route.

Comment: your components need to be inside the vue app not inside the index.html page, it is not reachable for the vue-router.